# MS Project File Associated with Multiple TFS Projects

Tags: tfs, project-management, project-planning, ms-project

Is there a way to associate a single MS Project file with multiple TFS projects?

Here is the situation: I have two projects that are related and have dependencies on each other and I would like to have one MS Project file to coordinate the schedule.  But, I do not see how I can associate (publish) to multiple TFS projects.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was trying to do is not possible.  The correct way to handle the problem is to create a master schedule where multiple project files are linked to a master project file.  Here is a video that describes this process:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvJIZ7lCEDw